# Error permission camera with unity render streaming when upload the build on app lab

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to create an app using unity that streams the meta quest pro screen to a browser using unity render streaming. I realized the problem was this package because by deleting it the problem was no longer being reported to me by meta quest developer hub. The Custom manifest that is in the plugins/andorid folder, it has no permissions to the camera but by decoding the apk and reading the manifest,  at run time, permissions were added to it.
How can I remove this permission or prevent it from being put ?

I am trying to upload the app on app lab in order to distribute on different quest and stream the screen on pc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.